# Open CV and ubuntu optimization in Beagleboard-xm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opencv, video-processing, beagleboard

I am doing video processing on beagleboard-xm with ubuntu installed in it. Ubuntu is with complete GUI but it is prebuilt image for omap3.Libraries used for these project is OpenCV.
So, the problem is whole process is too slow.Is there a way to fasten up the process like removing GUI? or removing unwanted packages?or installing of some optimized OS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

You can try  [Ångström Distribution](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) for Beagleboard may be faster than Ubntu.